# Map view crashing on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, crash, mapkit

Trying to fix a crash I'm getting in the simulator when using MapKit to display a map. It only occurs when switching between landscape and portrait. I've simplified the code while still replicating the crash to try to isolate the problem. Looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    init() {
        _region = .init(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)))
    }
    var body: some View {
        MapPreview(region: $region)
    }
}

struct MapPreview: View { 
    @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
            interactionModes: []
        )
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}
```

Crash message isn't much help, just gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT). Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is simulator bug.

Comment: having same issue.  oddly checking thread sanitizer removes the error when rotating with mapView on simulator but with no readout.